# Why does reusing GradientStopCollection cause an exception? (Value does not fall within the expected range)

Tags: drawing, silverlight-5.0

I'm using Silverlight to draw some shapes and text on top of an image. The shapes use a common set of gradient colors so I have a predefined set of GradientStopCollections that I intended to use to define the brushes used to fill the shapes. This works as long as I only use each of the GradientStopCollections up to one time. If I try to instantiate a LinearGradientBrush using one of the GradientStopCollections a second time, it throws an ArgumentException stating "Value does not fall within the expected range."

```
        _yellowFill = new GradientStopCollection();
        _yellowFill.Add(new GradientStop(){ Color = Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 255, 0), Offset = 0 });
        _yellowFill.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128, 0), Offset = 1 });
```

...

```
        _shapeLinearFillBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(_yellowFill, 90);
        ...
        _shapeLinearFillBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(_yellowFill, 90);
```

The last line above will throw the exception. Why is it throwing this exception and how can I use my GradientStopCollections to define multiple gradient brushes?

Comment: Have you tried referencing the collection as a static resource instead (e.g. in your App.XAML)?

Comment: @HiTechMagic No. I'm dynamically creating FrameworkElements to place in a canvas, so I am also dynamically creating their brushes (because I will modify them individually in response to events later). What would the difference be if I did?

Comment: Just brainstorming... It is possible that GradientStopCollection() is only allowed in one parent. I will need to delve into the dissassembly of GradientStopCollection to see why and get back to you.

Comment: What's strange is I get the exception even if I have no references to brushes using the collection anymore. I first found it when clearing the canvas and trying to redraw everything a second time.

Comment: @HiTechMagic As a test I tried creating a GradientStopCollection as a resource and then assigning it as a static resource to two different LinearGradientBrushes in XAML. It also blew up upon initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the issue has to do with Silverlight lacking freezable objects.  If you are using WPF, this should not be an issue.  There is no way in Silverlight to reuse the same GradientStopCollection.  I don't think that you can even use the same GradientStop.  To work around this you can create an extension method on that clones the GradientStopCollection like so:

```
_yellowFill = new GradientStopCollection();
_yellowFill.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 255, 0), Offset = 0 });
_yellowFill.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128, 0), Offset = 1 });

_shapeLinearFillBrush1 = new LinearGradientBrush(_yellowFill.Clone(), 90);
_shapeLinearFillBrush2 = new LinearGradientBrush(_yellowFill.Clone(), 90);

public static GradientStopCollection Clone(this GradientStopCollection stops)
{
    var collection = new GradientStopCollection();

    foreach (var stop in stops)
        collection.Add(new GradientStop() { Color = stop.Color, Offset = stop.Offset });

    return collection;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tjscience ! That was the same conclusion I came to and I ended up declaring my GradientStopCollections, more or less as templates, and cloning them instead of using them directly. I still don't understand why the lack of Freezable causes the exception though. How does it know the GradientStopCollection is already in use and why should it care?